# using strtol on a string literal causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, strtok, strtol

I have a string that I get by `getline()` (more precisely I use a loop and `getline` to read a file line by line)

Let's say the line is `12|34|`

Then I use strtok() to cut it down by `substr = strtok(line, "|");` 
and store them into a string array with a loop, `part[index] = substr;`

So the part[0] here should be "12" and part[0] is "34"
I would like to use strtol, but I have checked that it can't be used on string literal, then I try following code.

```
char *temp = strdup(part[1]);
char **ptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, ptr, 10);
printf("%x\n", ret);
```

and when I read the second line, it causes segmentation fault. By how can I really use `strtol` to convert the string into integer

Comment: Side note: At no point did you call `strtol` on a string literal, so I'm not sure where your title came from. Your original contention that `strtol` can't be called on string literals is wrong.

Comment: While all the observations about the wrong usage of ptr and strtol are right, I doubt this will cause a segmentation fault. Can you post a more complete version of your code? Especially the definition of part[] ?

Comment: @GermanNerd if you pass a non-null pointer to `strtol` it will try to write at this address, so yes, it's very likely to segfault (well, if your system has an MMU)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre The OP's code declared a pointer to char* . While uninitialized, it is allocated on the stack, and if the compiler accepts the implicit conversion from pointer to char* to char* (as gcc does), strtol() can write to it. Only when dereferencing the uninitialized pointer could you create a segfault.

Comment: yes, the `**ptr` pointer is allocated, but `strtol` _dereferences it_ (reads its value) to write something there (it's a pointer on pointer). So it's undefined behaviour. The value of `ptr` isn't valid for a pointer. Of course `&ptr` is initialized, but that's not the point.*

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I think we have a misunderstanding here. The problem is in the call to strtol(), where the '&' is missing. So yes, the OP's code could segfault if the newly allocated ptr does not happen to contain null. But the missing initialization in itself is not the problem.

Comment: It's missing an `&` so if you add `&` you have to declare `char *ptr` and initialize it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183008/discussion-between-germannerd-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: sorry, I can't, no chat at work.

Comment: Too bad. strtol wants to store a pointer to char. So we have to give it a pointer to pointer to char, right? As long as the compiler accepts the conversion (and on modern machines, usually all data pointers are the same), even smth. like char ****ptr; .... strtol(....&ptr...) would work. And if you do it the normal way, with a single char *, what would you initialize it to? The pointer's contents will be overwritten by strtol() anyhow.

Comment: @GermanNerd: You *don't* initialize the single `char*`. That's the point. `strtol` sets it for you when you pass the address of that `char*` to it; it doesn't read what's at the destination, so the initial value doesn't matter. As for using `char**` or more and passing `&thatvar`, just because all pointers are the same on most systems doesn't mean it's correct to do it. It needs a `char**`, you must pass the address of an existing `char*`, or you're in undefined behavior territory. Sure, most compilers accept all sorts of undefined behavior (though often with warnings), but that's no excuse.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree. It actually is partly rewording what I wanted to say: As long as you use &ptr in strtol(), it matters nothing if the pointer is uninitialized. To your second point with implicit conversions: If the compiler just throws a warning, I interpret that such that the compiler can and will do the conversion for you. Of course, you could always do an explicit cast, especially to a char pointer. Warnings gone. Don't get me wrong: The OP's code was wrong on two points, but only one of them was critical: the missing '&' in strtol.

Answer (score 3):

the issue is that `ptr` isn't initialised. So when `strtol` tries to write at the address `ptr`, it crashes (or undefined behaviour).

You have to pass the *valid* address of a pointer to store the last unprocessed char, like:

```
char *ptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, &ptr, 10);
```

`&ptr` is valid and points to the auto variable storage location to `ptr`

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing `strtol`. It takes a `char**` because it intends to set the `char*` it points to, per the man page:

> If `endptr` is not `NULL`, `strtol()` stores the address of the first invalid character in `*endptr`.

By passing it an uninitialized `char**` you invoke undefined behavior when it tries to dereference it. Change the code to:

```
char *ptr;  // Place to put the end ptr
long ret = strtol(temp, &ptr, 10);  // Pass address of the location it can set
```

Alternatively, if you never use `ptr`, just do:

```
long ret = strtol(temp, NULL, 10);  // Don't care about end ptr; strtol won't set on NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char **ptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, ptr, 10);
```

is wrong.  `ptr` is not initialized and doesn't refer to anything useful.

The second parameter of `strtol()` must refer to the address of an actual `char *` value that stores the address of the first non-converted character.  Per [**7.22.1.3 The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.3):

> A pointer to the final string is stored in the object pointed to by
>   endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.

The proper code would be

```
char *endptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, &endptr, 10);
```

or

```
char *endptr;
char **ptr = &endptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, ptr, 10);
```

In this case, after the call to `strtol()` the value in `endptr` would be the address of the first character that **wasn't** converted to the resulting `long` value.

If you don't care what the first non-converted character is:

```
char **ptr;
long ret = strtol(temp, NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you already have separated your string. 
So each string contains one long number. The second argument is used to  know where the conversion stopped in the string. 
If you don't need it, pass in `NULL`

```
char *temp = strdup(part[1]);
long ret = strtol(temp, NULL, 10);
printf("%lx\n", ret);
```

In addition `printf` for long number requires different format flags. Here `lx` for `long hexadecimal`.

Comment: The second argument doesn't *limit* the size of the conversion, it *reports* where it ended. Big difference.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to read a man apparently. My bad, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Function `strtol(const char *str, char **str_end, int base);` will dereference `str_end` and will do something like `*str_end = one_after_end_of_parsed_long`; So when you pass a pointer of type `char**`, which does not point to a valid pointer object that can be modified by `strtol` then, you'll yield undefined behaviour.

You'd rather write

```
char *ptr;  // space for taking on a pointer value
long ret = strtol(temp, &ptr, 10);
```

or (not the preferred variant):

```
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*));
long ret = strtol(temp, ptr, 10);
...
free(*ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to use `strtok()` at all, because `strtol()` sets the pointer pointed by the second parameter to point to the character following the number parsed.

A complete example program:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    *line_ptr = NULL;
    size_t   line_max = 0;
    ssize_t  line_len;

    long    *number      = NULL;
    size_t   numbers     = 0;
    size_t   numbers_max = 0;

    char    *curr, *next, *ends;
    long     temp;
    size_t   i;

    while (1) {

        line_len = getline(&line_ptr, &line_max, stdin);
        if (line_len < 1)
            break;

        curr = line_ptr;
        ends = line_ptr + line_len;

        numbers = 0;
        while (1) {

            /* Parse next long. */
            next = curr;
            errno = 0;
            temp = strtol(curr, &next, 0);
            if (errno)
                break;
            if (next == curr)
                break;

            /* Need to grow number array first? */
            if (numbers >= numbers_max) {
                size_t  temp_max = (numbers | 1023) + 1025 - 16;
                long   *temp_ptr;

                temp_ptr = realloc(number, temp_max * sizeof number[0]);
                if (!temp_ptr) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                numbers_max = temp_max;
                number      = temp_ptr;
            }

            /* Save parsed number. */
            number[numbers++] = temp;

            /* Skip trailing whitespace, */
            curr = next;
            while (curr < ends && (*curr == '\t' || *curr == '\n' || *curr == '\v' ||
                                   *curr == '\f' || *curr == '\r' || *curr == ' '))
                curr++;

            /* Skip separator. */
            if (*curr == '|')
                curr++;
            else
                break; /* No separator, so that was the final number. */
        }

        printf("Parsed %zu longs:", numbers);
        for (i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
            printf(" %ld", number[i]);
        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if (ferror(in)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading standard input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(line_ptr);
    line_ptr = NULL;
    line_max = 0;

    free(number);
    number = NULL;
    numbers = 0;
    numbers_max = 0;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Other than the available memory, this program has no limits wrt. line length or the amount of numbers it stores in the array.  The growth policy for the number array is funky (just my style); feel free to replace it with anything you prefer. Just make sure `temp_max` is at least `numbers + 1`. Making it larger means you allocate more at once, and therefore do fewer "slow" realloc() calls.

The outer `while` loop iterates over lines read from standard input.

The inner `while` loop parses the longs from that line, separated by a pipe character `|`. `strtol()` ignores leading whitespace. In case there is whitespace between the number and the following pipe character, we need to explicitly skip that; you could also use just `while (curr < ends && isspace(*curr)) curr++;` for that.

If you want to collect all the longs into a single array, rather than per line, just omit the `numbers = 0;` before the inner `while` loop. (And move printing out the numbers after the outer `while` loop.)

The actual conversion,

```
next = curr;
errno = 0;
temp = strtol(curr, &next, 0);
if (errno)
    break; /* errno == ERANGE; number too large in magnitude! */
if (next == curr)
    break; /* end of input, no number */
```

relies on the fact that if the number to be converted is too large in magnitude, `strtol()` will set `errno = ERANGE` and return `LONG_MIN` (if the number in the string was negative) or `LONG_MAX` (if positive). To detect that, we must set `errno` to zero first. If the string is empty (or there is a stray nul char, `\0`, in the line), `strtol()` will return 0 with `next == curr`.